# How do I exclude unit test from my android deploy

Tags: java, android, junit

I am attempting to add unit tests to an existing android project because I'm a good boy and am trying to do some cleanup. I'm doing this under intellij which is new to me. (I'm an eclipse person).

When I add junit, fine. When I add jmockit for a mocking framework, I get:

```
Android Dex: [ticket_2198a] Unable to execute DX
Android Dex: [ticket_2198a] com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define junit/framework/TestResult$1;
Android Dex: [ticket_2198a] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:592)
```

In my path, I've added jmockit first, then junit, and then the android libraries.

I have two questions:

1) Why are the unit tests getting compiled when I'm trying to deploy to the phone or emulator and how do I stop it.

2) Why is it blowing up?

Comment: You Khan(t) be serious. 1) How are you performing your build. 2) Looks like you've got a duplicate class being built.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am doing the build from inside intellij. I'm doing a debug on my android app which does a make. The duplicate class is because TestResult is in Android and jmockit and junit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this appears to be that you create a separate project for you unit tests. There is a project definition in Eclipse. More info here: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_eclipse.html.